# Convert sequential Monos to Flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a web service where I want to retrieve the elements of a tree up to the root node.
I have a Webflux interface which returns a Mono on each call:

```java
public interface WebService {
    Mono<Node> fetchNode(String nodeId);
}

public class Node {
    public String id;
    public String parentId; // null, if parent node
}
```

Let's assume there is a tree

```
    1
  2   3
  4   5
```

I want to create the following method:

```java
public interface ParentNodeResolver {

    Flux<Node> getNodeChain(String nodeId);
}
```

which would give me on `getNodeChain(5)` a Flux with the nodes for 5, 3 and 1 and then completes.

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand how I can combine Monos sequentially, but without blocking them. With `Flux.generate()`, I think I need to block on each mono to check whether it has a next element. Other methods which I've found seem to combine only a fixed number of Monos, but not in this recursive fashion.

Here is a sample code which would simulate the network request with some delay.

```java
public class MonoChaining {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    @Test
    void name() {
        var nodeChain = generateNodeChainFlux("5")
                .collectList()
                .block();
        assertThat(nodeChain).isNotEmpty();
    }

    private Flux<Node> generateNodeChainFlux(String nodeId) {
        //TODO
        return Flux.empty();


    }

    public Mono<Node> getSingleNode(String nodeId) {
        var future =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000); // Simulate delay
                        if ("5".equals(nodeId)) {
                            return new Node("5", "3");
                        } else if ("3".equals(nodeId)) {
                            return new Node("3", "1");
                        } else if ("1".equals(nodeId)) {
                            return new Node("1", null);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }, executorService);

        return Mono.fromFuture(future);
    }


    public static class Node {
        public String id;
        public String parentId;

        public Node(String id, String parentId) {
            this.id = id;
            this.parentId = parentId;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: you dont block, you fetch one, and use `flatMap` to read the value, and then take action within the flatMap. By the way, you can use Mono.fromCallable instead of CompletableFuture.fromAsync.

Answer (score 2):

The operator you are looking for is `Mono#expand`. It is used for recursively expanding sequences. Read more [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#expand-java.util.function.Function-).

In your case:

```java
private Flux<Node> generateNodeChainFlux(String nodeId) {
        return getSingleNode(nodeId).expand(node -> getSingleNode(node.parentId));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion with `flatMap` to get parent node and `concat` to append the current node to resulting `flux` might work. Try the code below:

```
public Flux<Node> getNodeChain(String nodeId) {
    return fetchNode(nodeId).flatMapMany(node -> {
        if (node.parent != null) {
            Flux<Node> nodeChain = getNodeChain(node.parent);
            return Flux.concat(Flux.just(node), nodeChain);
        }
        return Flux.just(node);
    });
}
```

Here I'm using `flatMapMany` to convert `Mono` to `Flux`.